# react native reset state in return() when set state

Tags: react-native

in react native I have a state like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        Time:0
    };

};
```

in componentDidMount  I set state like this:

```
var time = this.props.navigation.state.params.time * 60;

this.setState({Time: time });
```

and use this state in return function just like this :

```
<TimerCountdown
          initialSecondsRemaining={1000 *  this.state.Time}
          onTimeElapsed={() => {
               this.EndOfQuiz
          }}
          allowFontScaling={true}
          style={{ fontSize: 20, flex: 1, textAlign: 'center', }}
/>
```

now my problem is :

when I change other state with setState , Timer reset.
I change timer like this :

```
<TimerCountdown
          initialSecondsRemaining={1000 *  this.state.Time}
          onTick = {
             (secend)=>{
                this.setState({
                    Time : secend
                })
             }
          }
          onTimeElapsed={() => {
                this.EndOfQuiz
          }}
          allowFontScaling={true}
          style={{ fontSize: 20, flex: 1, textAlign: 'center', }}
/>
```

but I get an error :

[image: Maximum update depth exceeded.]

Comment: Can we see `TimerCountdown`? How often does onTick gets called?

Answer (score 0):

You can not set state inside render function. This will lead to multiple loops and will lead to crash as you are getting.

In your case it's leading to multiple loops and its causing crash because set state is not stopping, it's on inifinite loop

```
  onTick = {
             (secend)=>{
                this.setState({
                    Time : secend
                })
             }
          }
```

Your problem is here. You might need to tickle this function. The state is being fickling and causing an issue.